# Why won't accuracy increase when training this CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to train a CNN to recognize genre. Using the (small) FMA dataset, each 30s song segment has been translated into a mel-spectrogram using librosa. In turn, these spectrograms have been translated into 480x640x3 matrices (pixel height, pixel width, RGB-value), which in turn have been chopped up into three second segments with 50% overlap, yielding the final input matrices of size 480x64x3. The network I wrote aims to copy the network described in this (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09697.pdf) paper.

So in total I have 7197 mel-spectrograms as input, split into 3s with overlap yielding 7197*19 = 136743 matrices as input, and 800*19=15200 matrices as test data. There are eight genres for the network to learn, labeled 0-7.

When training, even after a couple of epochs, accuracy is still down at 0,125 (which equals pure guessing (1/8)). So what am I doing wrong?

```
import keras
#from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np

#THIS ARCHITECTURE IS TAKEN FROM: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09697.pdf
#3s with 50% overlap

batch_size = 64 #The set of examples used in one iteration (that is, one gradient update) of model training.
num_classes = 8 #1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
epochs = 20   

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 480, 64  #480x640 pixlar

# the data, split between train and test sets

(x_train, y_train) = (np.load('x_data_train_3s.npy'), np.load('y_data_train_3s.npy'))
(x_test, y_test) = (np.load('x_data_test_3s.npy'), np.load('y_data_test_3s.npy'))

x_train = x_train.reshape(136743,480,64,3) #this network accepts only 4-dim vector, so we reshape it. the last argument=grayscale. for RGB use 3. 
x_test = x_test.reshape(15200,480,64,3)

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
#y_train = y_train -5    #otherwise error in np_utils.py
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

#IMAGE DIMENSIONS
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),   #first layer
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(480,64,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #second layer, pooling
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 5), activation='relu')) #third layer
model.add(Dropout(0.25))     #dropout makes sure there is no overfitting, randomly switches of some neurons
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 4))) #fifth layer, pooling
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,   #compile the model with cross entropy loss function
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

model.save('genres.h5')
```

As the paper linked above, I expect accuracy to be around 0.7, but I get only 0.125. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.As your dataset is relatively small. You had to do data augmentation to achieve a better result.
2. Determining the right batch size is also a good factor for better result. Batch size 32 model and batch size 64 model may be differently produced a validation accuracy.
3. Decrease regularization parameter also helpful for getting a better result.

You have 5 pooling layers of size of 64 image into 3*3 size:
the first layer of pooling is 21*21 * 64
the fifth layer of pooling is 64  image into 2*4

It is quite much pooling.
Try 5*5 conv layers, max pool in 2*2 blocks then drop out before the fully connected layer. If the mention steps do not improve your result go for the tflearn a deep learning library with high-level API for Tensorflow.